# Converting a data structure of dtype=object to numpy array of dtype=float64

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I am trying to convert `'feature1'` array from the following data structure into a numpy array so I can input it to sklearn. However, I am running in circles as it always tells me that `dtype=object` is unsuitable, and I am not able to convert it to the desired `float64` format.

I want to extract all the `'feature1'` as a list of numpy arrays of `dtype=float64`, instead of `dtype=object` from the following structure.

`vec` is an object returned from an earlier computation.

```
>>>vec
[{'is_Primary': 1, 'feature1': [2, 2, 2, 0, 0.03333333333333333, 0], 'object_id': ObjectId('557beda51d41c8e4d1aeac25'), 'vectorized': 1},
{'is_Primary': 0, 'feature1': [2, 2, 1, 0, 0.5, 0], 'object_id': ObjectId('557beda51d41c8e4d1aeac25'), 'vectorized': 1}]
```

I tried the following:

```
>>> t = np.array(list(vec))
>>> t
>>>>array([ {'is_Primary': 0, 'feature1': [], 'object_id': ObjectId('557bcd881d41c8d9c5f5822f'), 'vectorized': 1},
   {'is_Primary': 0, 'feature1': [], 'object_id': ObjectId('557bcd881d41c8d9c5f58233'), 'vectorized': 1},
   {'is_Primary': 0, 'feature1': [], 'object_id': ObjectId('557bcd881d41c8d9c5f58237'), 'vectorized': 1},
   ...,
   {'is_Primary': 0, 'feature1': [], 'object_id': ObjectId('557beda61d41c8e4d1aead1f'), 'vectorized': 1},
   {'is_Primary': 1, 'feature1': [2, 2, 0, 0], 'object_id': ObjectId('557beda61d41c8e4d1aead1d'), 'vectorized': 1},
   {'is_Primary': 1, 'feature1': [], 'object_id': ObjectId('557beda61d41c8e4d1aead27'), 'vectorized': 1}], dtype=object)
```

Also,

```
>>> array = np.array([x['feature1'] for x in vec])
```

as suggested by another user, gives a similar output:

```
>>> array
>>> array([[], [], [], ..., [], [2, 2, 0, 0], []], dtype=object)
```

I know I can access the contents of `'feature1'` using `array[i]`, but what I want is to convert the `dtype=object` to `dtype=float64`, and made into a list/dict in which each row will have the `'feature1'`of the corresponding entry from `vec`.

I also tried using a pandas dataframe, but to no avail.

```
    >>>>pandaseries = pd.Series(df['feature1']).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
    >>>>pandaseries
0     []
1     []
2     []
3     []
4     []
5     []
6     []
7     []
8     []
9     []
10    []
11    []
12    []
13    []
14    []
...
7021                                                   []
7022    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 12, 2, 24...
7023                                                   []
7024                                                   []
7025                                                   []
7026                                                   []
7027                                                   []
7028    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 12, 2, 24...
7029                                                   []
7030    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 12, 2, 24...
7031                                                   []
7032                                       [2, 2, 0.1, 0]
7033                                                   []
7034                                         [2, 2, 0, 0]
7035                                                   []
Name: feature1, Length: 7036, dtype: object
    >>>
```

Again, `dtype: object` is returned. My guess would be to loop over each row and print a list out. But I am unable to do that. Maybe it is a newbie question. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: ```vec``` contains two dictionaries, each has a 'feature1' item.  Which one do you want?

Comment: If you don't know how to access the value of a dictionary item, maybe you should spend some time with [The Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) in the docs.

Comment: I want both as the rows of a numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

Lets take as the starting point a list of lists or equivalently an object array of lists:

```
A = [[], [], [], [1,2,1], [], [2, 2, 0, 0], []]
A = array([[], [], [], [1,2,1], [], [2, 2, 0, 0], []], dtype=object)
```

If the sublists were all the same length, `np.array([...])` would give you a 2d array, one row for each sublist, and columns matching their common length.  But since they are unequal in length, it can only make it a 1d array, where each element is a pointer to one of these sublists - i.e. dtype=object.

I can imagine 2 ways of constructing a 2d array:

- pad each sublist to a common length
- insert each sublist into an empty array of the appropriate size.

Basically it requires common Python iteration;  it's not a common enough task to have a wiz-bang numpy function.

For example:

```
In [346]: n=len(A)
In [348]: m=max([len(x) for x in A])
In [349]: AA=np.zeros((n,m),int)
In [350]: for i,x in enumerate(A):
   .....:     AA[i,:len(x)] = x
In [351]: AA
Out[351]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

To get a sparse matrix:

```
In [352]: from scipy import sparse
In [353]: MA=sparse.coo_matrix(AA)
In [354]: MA
Out[354]: 
<7x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 5 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Nothing magical, just straight forward sparse matrix construction.  I suppose you could bypass the dense matrix

There is a list-of-lists sparse format that looks a bit like your data.

```
In [356]: Ml=MA.tolil()

In [357]: Ml.rows
Out[357]: array([[], [], [], [0, 1, 2], [], [0, 1], []], dtype=object)

In [358]: Ml.data
Out[358]: array([[], [], [], [1, 2, 1], [], [2, 2], []], dtype=object)
```

Conceivably you could construct an empty `sparse.lil_matrix((n,m))` matrix, and set it's `.data` attribute directly.  But you'd also have to calculate the `rows` attribute.

You could also look at the `data`, `row`. `col` attributes of the `coo` format matrix, and decide it would be easy to construct the equivalent from your `A` list of lists.

One way or other you have to decide how the non-zero rows get padded to the full length.

Comment: Thanks! Basically this solves my problem. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600397/2d-list-to-numpy-array-and-fill-remaining-values-of-shorter-sublists-with-1)

Comment: **This is the canonical answer.** But wait: *that's not all.* This answer also serves as a readable introduction to numpy-fication of lists-of-lists (i.e., coercion of ragged Python lists into uniform NumPy matrices) *and* sparsification of matrices (i.e., coercion of uniform NumPy matrices into their sparse equivalents). In short, this answer exemplifies why I regularly return to StackOverflow. Bravissimo!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
array = numpy.array ( [ x['feature1'] for x in ver ] )
```

Or you need to be more clear in your example...

Comment: You must explain your answer, also what about OP wants the `'feature1'`values in a separate numpy array?

Comment: The OP wants the values as rows of an array.  That's what this answer produces.  But whether all `feature1` values have the same length makes a big difference in the resulting array type.

Comment: @hpaulj yes the length of each row is different, and i was hoping this would give me a sparse numpy array that would be accessible to `scipy.sparse`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of a dictionary item by using its key:

```
d ={'a':1}
d['a'] --> 1
```

To *access* items in a list, you can iterate over it or use its index

```
a = [1,  2]

for thing in a:
    # do something with thing

a[0]  --> 1
```

`map` conveniently applies a function to all the items of an iterable and returns a list of the *results*.  `operator.getitem` returns a function that will *retrieve* an item from an object.

```
import operator
import numpy as np
feature1 = operator.getitem('feature1')
a = np.asarray(map(feature1, vec))
```

---

```
vec = [{'is_Primary': 1, 'feature1': [2, 2, 2, 0, 0.03333333333333333, 0], 'object_id': ObjectId('557beda51d41c8e4d1aeac25'), 'vectorized': 1},
       {'is_Primary': 0, 'feature1': [2, 2, 1, 0, 0.5, 0], 'object_id': ObjectId('557beda51d41c8e4d1aeac25'), 'vectorized': 1}]

>>> a = np.asanyarray(map(feature1, vec))
>>> a.shape
(2, 6)
>>> print a
[[ 2.          2.          2.          0.          0.03333333  0.        ]
 [ 2.          2.          1.          0.          0.5         0.        ]]
>>> 
>>> for thing in a[1,:]:
    print type(thing)

<type 'numpy.float64'>
<type 'numpy.float64'>
<type 'numpy.float64'>
<type 'numpy.float64'>
<type 'numpy.float64'>
<type 'numpy.float64'>
>>>
```

Comment: Maybe it's just a matter of style, but I think `[ x['feature1'] for x in ver ]` is more idiomatic, but functionally the same, as your `map(operator...)`.

Comment: @hpaulj .. List comprehensions are cool and a lot of ppl (most) seem to think they are THE idiomatic form.  For some reason I like ```map``` - but do use list comprehensions. Sometimes list comprehensions are faster sometimes ```map``` is faster (if time is important).

Comment: @wwii Your suggestion provided a string.

Comment: @ShantanuGhosh - Using the example for ```vec``` that was provided, I get an ndarray of shape (2,6) and type float64.  Is your data different than the example in the question?